# Key ordering when json_encode php variable (array) into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, encode

When try to json_encode a php array variable into javascript variable have an issue:

```
var duration_options = <?=json_encode($duration_options)?>;
        var duration_options_items = '';
        $.each(duration_options,function(index, value) {
            if(init_act_duration == value){
                var selected_option = 'selected=selected';
                }else{
                var selected_option = '';
            }
            duration_options_items = duration_options_items + '<option value="'+index+'" '+selected_option+'>'+value+'</option>';
        });

        duration_options_items = '<select class="form-control select2 select_ajax select_ajax_duration" name="edit_activity_duration" style="width:100%">'+duration_options_items+'</select>';
```

The PHP array is

```
    Array
(
    [0.5] => 0.5
    [1] => 1
    [1.5] => 1.5
    [2] => 2
    [2.5] => 2.5
    [3] => 3
    [3.5] => 3.5
    [4] => 4
)
```

After json_encode when I use that json in my javascript the array is like:

```
  Array
    (

        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 4
        [0.5] => 0.5
        [1.5] => 1.5
        [2.5] => 2.5
        [3.5] => 3.5
    )
```

Just can't understand it why and have no idea how to ordering them properly

Comment: _After json_encode becomes: ..._ Is that really a Javascript array?

Comment: check this:-  https://eval.in/557376      . It clearly states that you are doing something with your array before `json_encode`

Comment: Please edit the question and post your code. Don't just assume PHP is broken ;-)

Comment: @Anant Not necessarily, just paste the encoded json in your browser console (chrome in my case), and you'll see the *reordered* version. Problem is, the question is probably missing the *"when I use that json in my javascript..."* portion.

Comment: Just use `json_encode(array_values($duration_options));`, the decimal keys don't make much sense anyway (keys are equal to values).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I edited my question with the jQuery code that I use for getting the json_encode php variable

Comment: @Yoshi It's works perfect.
Just had to make a increment value += 0.5 to set the values of <option> because keys of the new array are 0,1,2,3,4, not 0.5,1,1.5 but is ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are observing this behaviour because your array does not contain integer *and* sequential keys. So, `json_encode` maps it to a JSON **object**.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you assume the JSON is wrong but you haven't really inspected it (there're several ways to do so, such as the *Net* pane in your browser's developer tools).

As soon as you parse it from JavaScript it becomes a JavaScript **object**. As such, the order of keys is not guaranteed because that's how the ECMAScript spec defines objects.

If you need bullet-proof order, you need to switch to regular **arrays**, i.e., with consecutive zero-based integer keys.

Answer (score -1):

And what is the problem with this, you have same keys so you can use them the same? It seems it sort by length key and then natural.

When you loop use keys.

Comment: I edited my question to see that I use the json_encode php variable to make select / option dropdown with loop